# Auto sync recently captured image into ionic app android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to sync image or video to my ionic app as soon as user captures image or video. I got many solutions to capture image from ionic app. I even got the answer for manually selecting the picture from gallery, but I do not need that.

I want to achieve something as described by below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIlro.png)

[ShoeBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.couchlabs.shoebox&hl=en) an app that is automatically syncs that image into their app after user takes a photo.

I want to do exactly the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what did you try yourself ? You should take a look at [ask] ;) we will not provide you a fully developed solution, but we can help you to resolve a focused problem

Comment: I only need a way to achieve auto syncing image in app through camera through ionic, I searched a lot, but couldnt find a particular way to do that, so any hint regarding plugins or something that will be of help

Comment: as you could see, no answer from anybody. Again, I encourage you to read [ask] ;)

Comment: did you find anything about it?